# Date and appointment in advance?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am stuck on two problems.

1)- I have a table named "Course" with 4 fields (`date_seance`, `hour_start`, `hour_end`, `fk_bike`).

My first problem is that I can not plan dates in advance.

For example, if I reserve a date on `01/09/2019` for the bike `000001`.

I must be able to book another booking on `02/09/2019` with the same bike. So, `000001`.

```php
public function store(courseRequest $request)
{
    $exists = Course::where('date_seance', $request->get('date_seance'))
        ->where('hour_start', $request->get('hour_start'))
        ->where('hour_end', $request->get('hour_end'))
        ->where('fk_bike', $request->get('fk_bike'))
        ->count();

    $date_seance = $request->get('date_seance');

    $conflict = Course::where('fk_bike', $request->get('fk_bike'))
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "<=" , $date_seance)
        ->whereDate('date_seance ', ">=", $date_seance)
        ->first();

    $conflict2 = Course::where('fk_bike', $request->get('fk_bike'))
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "<=" , $ date_seance)
        ->whereDate('date_seance', ">=", $date_seance)
        ->first();

    if (isset($conflict2) || isset($conflict)){
        return redirect()->route('courses.index')
            ->with('error', 'Duplicate ');
    } else {
        Course::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('courses.index')
            ->with('success', Add !);
    }
}
```

2)- Second question, if I add a `fk_former`, do you have an idea of the syntax?

Comment: Am I missing something? The only reason you can't do what you want is because you've written your `store()` method that way. Just remove the duplicate check. No?

Comment: Hard to understand what you are trying to do. Your code checks if the same bike has every been booked before, and fails if it has. So you will only ever be able to book a bike on one day ... what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Don't Panic: I would like to reserve several bikes in advance.
And manage duplicates.

Comment: Sounds like you should be checking if the bike has been booked on the **same** day, not **any other** day, no?  And why do the same conflict check twice?