# training & appointment in advance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table named "Training" with 4 fields `(date_seance, hour_start, hour_end, fk_bike)`.

My first problem is that I can not plan dates in advance.

For example, if I reserve a date on `01/09/2019` for the bike `000001`. It works but if, I must to book another booking on `02/09/2019` with the same bike. So, 000001 I don't see the bike `000001` in my dropdownlist.

Do you have an idea ? Please...

```
public function index()
{
    $trainings = Training::oldest()->paginate(5);
    return view('admin.trainings.index', compact('trainings'))
      ->with('i', (request()->input('page',1) -1)*5);
}



public function store(Request $request)
    {   

        $request->validate([
                 'date_seance' => 'required',
         'hour_start' => 'required',
             'hour_end' => 'required',
                 'fk_bike' => 'required'
        ]);

        Training::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
    }
```

I thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: The question text sounds identical to [the question you asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767430/date-and-appointment-in-advance), but the code is different and does not seem to match your question.  Please don't open duplicate questions.  If this is not a duplicate, please edit it and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
{
   $trainings = Training::all()->pluck('fk_bike','fk_bike');
   return view('admin.trainings.index', compact('trainings'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have an error message of synthax `"syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'",` i think it's here? `('fk_bike','fk_bike');`

Comment: You should add a little bit of explanation before the code.